# I want to add Company name in Customer grid during order creation

Tags: magento2

I want to add Company Name in Customer grid during order creation. Can any one help me how can we do that in magento2.We need to extened sales_order_create_customer_block.xml, but i can't able make it. Please help me.
Here are my code screenshtots with output
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're right. We need to update this  `sales_order_create_customer_block.xml` layout file for company attribute but alongside this we also need to extend the grid collection.

Because the collection, which is being used to populate customer grid data doesn't include company attribute by default.

So after adding company attribute to the collection, we can add a new block instance for company column in grid columnSet.

Here are the steps to do so in your custom module.

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_customer_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">\{Namespace}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="company" after="billing_postcode">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">company</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Customer/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'company',
            'customer_address/company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me what other files do i need create to create an extension for this functionality

Comment: Do i require Model's also?

Comment: No.. You just need xml and collection class as mentioned in answer

Comment: You Code added grid with Compnay name, But i can't get COmpany Names wrt to user's. In customer_grid_flat table field name is billing_company so i changed code to this 
 parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'billing_company',
            'customer_address/billing_company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );
bit it's not working

Comment: the same code will work if the customer already has an address saved with the company information. please share your Magento version.

Comment: I think collection is not calling

Comment: My magento version is 2.1.8

Comment: I somehow able to call collection

Comment: Happy to hear that... What was the hack??

Comment: <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container"> in this code i removed adminhtml

Comment: Hi! I am trying to do the same thing but the Company column is not being populated with the data. Can you please update the answer to show how you got it working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the answer to this question, I was able to get everything working.

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Customer/Collection.php

```
<?php
namespace {Namespace}\{Module}\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();
        $this->joinAttribute(
            'billing_company',
            'customer_address/company',
            'default_billing',
            null,
            'left'
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app/code/{Namespace}/{Module}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_customer_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Trucatch\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
            </arguments>
            <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.columnSet">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="billing_company" after="name">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Company</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">billing_company</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

The difference between this solution and @Shyam is the second referenceBlock needs to be within the first referenceBlock.

Comment: can any buddy share complete module.. to add company name is sales order coloumn